Making wobbly 6x4’ table stable
I'm a complete novice to woodworking and have built a 6x4 foot baseboard for my model railway. The top is made of three sections bolted together. The base top is 9mm ply topped with 9mm Sundeala board.
I've attempted to make removable legs as I want to be able to dismantle the table for storing.
The legs are made of 18x70mm wood and are cross braced on the short side of the table using 7.5mm tounge and grove cladding boards. The legs slot into pockets in the corners of the underside of the board. I'm trying to avoid braces that run the entire horizontal distance on the long side as this would get in the way and prevent access to the underside of the table. Though I do think it needs some braces somewhere.
The table while standing is somewhat wobbly. I would like to shore it up ideally without anything too complex or expensive. While being easy to remove. Even if that means unscrewing things to put it away.
I'm t trying to do this as cheap as possible given the high prices in the UK.
I have some 18x70 wood left over.
Would love suggestions and help. I have tools including a meter saw.
Thanks in advance.



Update:
Thanks for all the advice and help. I’ve added diagonal stretchers at 42 degrees from the legs to the frame and added central legs to prevent table from sagging. I’ve added M8 bolts and fixing to all legs as well.  Lastly I’ve added multiple screws to horizontal stretchers too. The table is very stable on the long side. Still a bit wobbly on the short side due to the legs being quite thin but not enough to worry about.



Adding rubber feet to the bottoms of the legs might help a little with the stability, or at least stop the chance of the table sliding on the smooth floor when the train changes direction.

One word: diagonals. More lightly built workbenches are often a bit wobbly, but adding diagonal bracing to any such design instantly yields a big improvement in stability. The reason is that there's a tendency for the square/rectangle formed by legs to 'parallelogram' and this is reduced, possibly to nearly zero, by the introduction of one or more diagonals.
Actually two words: because, panels. Another way of achieving the same end as above is by attaching panels. If you pin a panel to any rectangular assembly it becomes impossible for it to change geometry. While this panel is often almost the full size of the rectangle (as in the solid backs of cupboards and bookcases) just a quite wide one, e.g. triple the width of your stretchers, can be sufficient and of course this saves a lot of material.
In addition, the panel material does not need to be substantial for this to work. 6mm stuff is often perfectly adequate, as long as it's affixed firmly (glued on, or attached with lots of nails or small screws). You might even be able to get away with 3mm, but I would suggest you err on the side of guaranteed strength here and go with 6mm.
And a further buying tip if you want to go this route, look for offcuts. These may be sold off at a substantial reduction, depending on source. My closest B&Q at one point nearly gave away plywood, hardboard and MDF offcuts, which is how I could build my workbench for a materials cost of way under 50 quid (allowing me to forever joke that the vice cost more than the entire bench LOL).

Some construction notes for future reference.
Even for a table of much more modest size your leg assemblies could have done with being quite a bit more substantial than this; in short, beefier wood all around (wider legs, thicker stretchers). As-is, and despite firmer fixing between the elements, there's flex possible simply within the material itself.
But the minimal fixing between elements is a big contributing factor here. Using a single fixing screw at each location means there's scope for rotation at each site, which of course is not stable. So just by more securely connecting all elements you'd get some improvement.

Thank you. I might replace the current stretchers with something thicker and use multiple screws to avoid rotation. In relation to the diagonals how would that look and how do I go about building that?

I don't think it's necessary to replace your stretchers if you'll be reinforcing in multiple ways. By all means do so if you want to, but additional bracing and firmer fixing will do a lot, and my guess is probably enough. Diagonal bracing at its simplest as pictured in the other Answer of course. This obviously requires longer boards; if you don't have any boards of sufficient length already plywood/MDF offcuts are probably going to be cheaper.

This isn't doing you much good:

The braces can just turn around the screw.  You really need two screws for them to do anything.
Like this:

You could also switch to diagonal braces.
Sides:

Back:

That's a high desk that I use daily.  I sit on an exercise bike that fits under the desktop.  It is solid enough to hold a laptop and two monitors, with me leaning on it as I work.  The front has no braces, but the braces on the back and both sides gives it enough stability.

Thank you. I’m looking for a bracing solution that won’t block access from both the long sides of the bench. Is there an option of bracing from the legs to the frame instead of legs to legs to allow sitting under the table? Also I need to be able to dismantle the legs so everything needs to be removable.

@Camsoft Use smaller diagonals. They don't have to go all the way down to the floor. You might get enough stability by adding small diagonals in the corners.
